# ADT array with base class being abstract

Tags: c++, arrays, abstract-class

Is it possible to have an ADT (Abstract Data Type) array that contains pointers of the base class, said class being abstract? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: One way is `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myADT>> arr;`

Comment: hey @πάνταῥεῖ we meet again, yeah but i was thinking about `array=new object[size]` or something, as it is better for me.. but that wouldn't work because of abstract classes definition

Comment: _abstract classes_ cannot be instantiated, thus you'll need pointers.

Comment: infact, i tried:
`object* array;` and `array=new object[size];`

Comment: _"as it is better for me"_ Why so? What I advised would work right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an instance of an abstract class. You can have a reference (but you cannot have arrays of references) and you can have pointers.

Pointers to a base class that is abstract are perfectly fine, and you can place them in arrays without problems.